# Desktop Google Chrome Push notification not receiving

Tags: google-chrome, push

I Added project in console.developers.google.com. Then enabled Google Cloud Messaging for Android and Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome. Then Created Server Key. But when i try to send push notification a have no succes.

When I POST

```
curl --header "Authorization: key=MY_KEY" --header Content-Type:"application/json" https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"APA91bFQCjfnY0pbBrZVxXK_muivZ6LtnbFE_E3ep8INHS9mTS-TBko4xzfvVzxC-7BuxWD6d4rAR6JSA9hBBufcno1yWgaKMJZgbsS9k3mJqJjNJawKB3d7Dne6GFHR7UmxbXv3YV3vFGeUkKU2k9-CiHnfbjEwY9qXmlHZhbdkTqm888i7oUs\"]}"
```

I have this responce

```
{
  "multicast_id": 9087785123467340172, 
  "success": 1, 
  "failure": 0, 
  "canonical_ids": 0, 
  "results":[{ 
    "message_id": 0:1442045853263680%ed757c9bf9fd7ecd"
  }]
}
```

But i see no notification

```
registration_ids
```

Is my registration id

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting message on crome-dev-tool windows regarding push notification?
if yes then you have to make service-worker.js file of main and completed folder same and then refresh chrome to update service-worker. It should work when you will send again through curl.